# Set theory and Probability - Variant of Union Bound (Boole's Law)

Tags: probability

Let $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots$ be a collection of events. Is this true or false?
$$\mathrm{Pr}\left (  \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} A_{k}\right ) \leq  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathrm{Pr}(A_{k})$$

Comment: Yes, here's my idea:
This is always true $Pr\left (  \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_{k}\right ) \leq  \sum_{k=1}^{n}Pr(A_{k})$

Comment: And since the intersection is always less than the union, then it holds that the intersection is always less than the sum of the individual probabilities

Comment: But, that's a $_\leq$ symbol, meaning at some point it has to be equal to the sum. That's the problem.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Any ideas?

Comment: Your argument is correct. Because the set $\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k$ is contained inside $\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$, we know that
$$\mathrm{Pr}\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k\right)\leq\mathrm{Pr}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right),$$
and we also know that
$$\mathrm{Pr}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right)\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\mathrm{Pr}(A_k).$$
Put those two inequalities together, and you're done. So I don't understand your confusion - what do you mean by "at some point"? Either the inequality holds, or it doesn't.

Comment: What scenario validates the "equal to" part of the relation.

Comment: I'm saying, shouldn't it just be $\Pr\left (  \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} A_{k}\right ) < \sum_{k=1}^{n}Pr(A_{k})$

Comment: No. If $x\leq y$, and $y\leq z$, then $x\leq z$. For example, let $x=1$, $y=2$, and $z=3$. You could also have $x=y=z=1$, in which case it ***is*** true that $x=z$, but it need not *always* be true that $x=z$.

Comment: I understand. Here's what I', saying: Say the two sets fully overlap, then the sum of the probabilities is 2 (yeah doesn't make sense), but the probability of the intersection is still 1, which is less than 2.  Can't seem to think of a case when they p(intersection) =  sum of p(events)

Comment: Take all the sets $A_k$ to be sets of probability $0$. Then $$\mathrm{Pr}\left (  \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} A_{k}\right ) =  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathrm{Pr}(A_{k})$$ with both sides being equal to $0$. So you cannot replace $\leq$ by $<$ unless you exclude this case (and possibly others) from the kinds of events for which your improved claim is true.

Comment: @Virgo: It doesn't matter whether equality can or can't occur. It is a *correct statement* to say that
$$1\leq 2$$
even though $1$ has no hope of ever being equal to $2$. Similarly,
$$\mathrm{Pr}\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k\right)\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\mathrm{Pr}(A_k)$$
is always true. Incidentally, it ***is*** possible to have equality - suppose that all your events $A_k$ have probability $0$. Or, you could just take a single event $A_1$ (that is, let $n=1$); in this case you'll also have equality.

Comment: Yes, I considered the case of n=1, but everyone in my group seems to disagree. I actually believe the statements is true, but I want cogent evidence, which you guys seem to have provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is true, but may be a MASSIVE (more massive than the actual union bound) over estimate; much better is
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{P}P\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A_k\right)\leq\min_{1\leq k\leq n}P(A_k),
$$
or
$$
\P\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A_k\right)\leq P(A_i)\text{ for all }1\leq i\leq n.
$$
Both are immediately true because $\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A_k\subseteq A_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ (and the first is an immediate consequence of the second).

Comment: Makes sense, but is there a case when they are actually equal?
Say the two sets fully overlap, then the sum of the probabilities is 2 (yeah doesn't make sense), but  the probability of the intersection is still 1.

Comment: Which is less than 2.

Comment: Which "they" are you asking about?

Comment: When the sum of intersection actually equals the sum of the individual probabilities. For example, if the sets are disjoint, the probability of the union equal the sum of the individual probabilities. In the case of intersection, when can they be equal?

Comment: You mean when the probability of the intersection is the sum of the individual probabilities?  The only time this is true is if $P(A_k)=0$ for all $k$.  This can be proved by induction; think about the case $n=2$, for instance.  We know that $P(A_1\cap A_2)\leq P(A_1)$; so, if $P(A_1\cap A_2)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)$, then necessarily $P(A_2)=0$. The same argument but switching $A_1$ and $A_2$ shows that $P(A_1)=0$ as well.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's the only case, but is it valid to assume that two empty sets have an intersection?

Comment: Yes.  The intersection of two empty sets is the empty set.  Also: $P(A_k)=0$ does not mean that $A_k$ is the empty set.

Comment: Okay, for some reason, I excluded the zero possibilities. Thank you.